# Limit displayed length of string on web page

Tags: javascript, css, string, dhtml

I'm looking for a technique (javascript, CSS, whatever ???) that will let me control the amount of a string that is displayed. The string is the result of a search (and therefore not initially known). A simple Character count approach is trivial, but not acceptable, as it needs to handle proportional fonts. In otherwords if I want to limit to say 70 pixels then the examples below show different character counts (9 and 15) both measuring the same:-

Welcome M...
Hi Iain if I've ...

If you look at Yahoo search results they are able to limit the length of title strings and add ellipsis on the end of long strings to indicate more.
(try  site:loot.com wireless+keyboard+and+mouse to see an example of Yahoo achieving this)

Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I indicate long text into a smaller fixed column with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108740/how-do-i-indicate-long-text-into-a-smaller-fixed-column-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the CSS property `overflow: hidden;` can help you, in conjuntion with `width`.

Comment: Thanks - Great start!

  style='overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:1.2em'

successfully handles the limiting of length (you have to add height to stop the wrap).

The only downside is I can't think of anyway of know whether there was an overflow, therefore I don't know whether to add the ellipis.

Comment: rather then applying a height - because we all know that's not fun... try using white-space:nowrap CSS property. This will force all lines to stay on one line :D

Answer (score 1):

Using a span with fixed width, overflow-x:hidden and white-space:nowrap would be a start.

To get the elipsis in a cross browser scenario will be difficult.  IE has text-overflow:elipsis but that is non-standard.  This is emulated with -o-text-overflow in Opera.  However mozilla doesn't have this.  The yahoo Javascript APIs handle this.

Comment: I think you need overflow-x: hidden. Or just go with overflow: hidden to be safe.

Comment: oops you're right typo overflow-y makes no sense on a span, will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo does this server-side, the truncation and elipsis ('...') is returned in the HTML. Presumably this is done on a character count, and if thats not an option for you then server-side is out.

Other than `overflow: hidden` I'm not sure CSS can help you here. You could measure the width of the containing element using Javascript, and truncate the text based on that. This could be used in conjunctin with `overflow:hidden;` so the text elements don't just resize all of a sudden, but you may have to extract the text and add a temporary element onto the page somewhere to do the measurement. Depending on the number of elements to truncate this might not work very well.

Another slightly hacky option is to measure the width of an element containing the letter '`W`', then do a character count and truncate if `(char_count * width_of_w) > desired_width`.

You can use `text-wrap: none;` to stop text wrapping onto new lines, although this is a CSS3 property and last I checked was only supported by IE (imagine my shock when I found that one out!).

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-browser pure-CSS solution, take a look at Hedger Wang's text-overflow:ellipsis prototype, here:

http://www.hedgerwow.com/360/dhtml/text_overflow/demo2.php

Answer (score 0):

> In CSS: .class-name{
>       width: 5em;
>       white-space: nowrap;
>       text-overflow: ellipsis; }
>
> Hope it can help you.