# Cut a string to fit the width of a div and add three dots at the end of the string

Tags: c#, css

How can I cut a string to fit to the width of a div?

Let's say I have a long string, like `"Anyone can help me to solve this problem"` to put in a div 80px wide. What I want is to cut the string to fit the width of the div and add "..." at the end of a word, as in `"Anyone can help me..."`

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282758/truncate-a-string-nicely-to-fit-within-a-given-pixel-width

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195408/limit-displayed-length-of-string-on-web-page is very similar, and another one I saw yesterday but can't find now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I indicate long text into a smaller fixed column with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108740/how-do-i-indicate-long-text-into-a-smaller-fixed-column-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use CSS to truncate the string with an ellipsis using methods such as [this one by Justin Maxwell](http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/).

Basically, to make it work cross-browser, you have to use a combination of standard CSS, browser-specific CSS and some XML. The full writeup can be read at the link above, but the end product is:

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding: url('assets/xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}
```

combined with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
>
    <binding id="ellipsis">
        <content>
            <xul:window>
                <xul:description crop="end" xbl:inherits="value=xbl:text"><children/></xul:description>
            </xul:window>
        </content>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

Then decorate your div with the CSS class="ellipsis"

Comment: Touche. I still think its a FF hack though :p

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no know where to cut the string. You *could* use JavaScript to lop off characters one by one until the width is <= 80px, then append a ... but I wouldn't recommend it. A better way would be to crop your string to some length you *know* will be longer than 80px, then with CSS put `overflow:hidden` on your `div`, and overlay your ... as a separate element and align to the right of the div. It might appear slightly off, but I think it's the best you can do. Gmail does something like this. They crop it to a predefined number of characters, slap on a ... and hide anything that's still too long.