# How do I indicate long text into a smaller fixed column with CSS?

Tags: css, string, truncate

How do I fit long text into a fixed width column where I have room for only one line of text? The text needs to be cut to a fixed width *(lets say to 100px)* and I would like to add dots "..." at the end. Something like this for example:

Given string:

```
Some really long string that I need to fit in there!
```

Desired output in fixed-width-column should be:

```
Some really long string...
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can do this with CSS alone:

```
.box {
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   /* Opera */
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;   /* IE, Safari (WebKit) */
    overflow:hidden;              /* don't show excess chars */
    white-space:nowrap;           /* force single line */
    width: 300px;                 /* fixed width */
}
```

Note: You will want to check on the latest browser support.

Comment: Cool! I coded up a kind-of-working solution before I saw your answer. https://gist.github.com/708155

Comment: This: "text-overflow: ellipsis;" is all that is needed now in all current versions of IE, Opera, Firefox, Chrome & Safari so only need the work arounds (and "-o-text-overflow:") for older browser support.

Comment: What about a multi-line text solution? This will only work for single line of text. What for-example if I have place for 3 lines of text and I wand that '...' is added in the last line where the text is clipped?

Answer (score 2):

Just with some CSS like answer of Gordon. Just added the `display:block` property for an inline element like `<a>` or `<p>` :

```
a#myText{
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
}
```

You could use it with many browser like you can see on this link :
http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the way I solved it was to strip the string down to 60 characters and append an '...' to the end of it.

An ugly solution? Yes, but unless there is a jQuery solution it's probably your best bet.

If you're using Smarty, this is how I solved the problem:

```
{$my_string|truncate:60}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I use to truncate strings. Like most of the suggestions here, it uses substr to truncate the string, but it will avoid splitting the string mid-word:

```
function truncate_text($string, $min_chars, $append = ' &hellip;') {
    $chars = strpos($string, " ", $min_chars);
    $truncated_string = substr($string, 0, $chars) . $append;
    return $truncated_rstring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simple cutting text after N characters isn't what you're looking for. It's not a solution because the following text have both 15 character length: iiiiiiiiiiiiiii, mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm - notice that the second "word" is about three times longer than the first one.

JavaScript might be a solution:

1. First prepare your mark-up:

   ```
   <p id="abc">{TEXT}</p>
   ```

   Where `{TEXT}` is your text truncated to 150 characters + `...`
2. Now when we've got a good base for JavaScript we can try to make what you're looking for:

   ```
   <html>
   <head> 
       <style type="text/css">
           #abc {
               width: 100px;
           }
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
               var ref  = document.getElementById("abc");
               var text = ref.text;

               ref.removeChild(ref.firstChild);
               ref.appendChild(document.createTextNode("..."));

               var maxHeight = ref.offsetHeight;

               var pos = 0;
               while (ref.offsetHeight <= maxHeight) {
                   var insert = text.substring(0, ++pos) + "...";

                   var finalReplace = ref.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(insert), ref.firstChild);
               }

               ref.replaceChild(finalReplace, ref.firstChild);
           }, false);
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p id="abc">My very, very, very, very, very, very, very long text...</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```